# How to increase the sample rate of the current measured from the Android kernel?

Tags: battery, linux, kernel

I need to monitor some applications power consumption of my Samsung A8, programmatically. I'm doing this by accessing the files:

`/sys/class/power_supply/battery/current_now` 
`/sys/class/power_supply/battery/voltage_now`

The problem is that the kernel update those files every 10 seconds, so it does not produce sufficient power samples measurement to my experiment. I want to reduce the update time produced by the kernel driver to increase the sample rate. Ideally the kernel would update the values every half second.

From this post: [How does the Android estimate the battery level without a current sensor?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46160/how-does-the-android-estimate-the-battery-level-without-a-current-sensor)
I understood that I might find the name of the chip that measures the battery information by looking into a defconfig file. After searching for a while on the defconfigs from my kernel, I believe that the Fuel Gauge used is S2MU004 as specified in this file: https://github.com/prashantpaddune/universal7885/blob/e5ffd23305f0b09fe2bef3f8580df046dab232cc/arch/arm64/configs/exynos7885-jackpotlte_defconfig#L4415

But I'm still not sure about it. Would be the s2mu004-fuelgauge the name of the chip? If so, where can I find the driver? And then, someone can enlighten me on how to modify the driver to increase the sample rate?

**Device Information** 
**Model:** Samsung Galaxy A8 (SM-A530F) 
**Android Version:** Android Pie (9) 
**Kernel:** Quantum Kernel V4 
**Kernel version:** 4.4.111-Quantum_pie.V4.0-A530F 
**Processor:** Samsung Exynos Octa 7885 
**Magisk version:** (used for root) 19.3

Comment: The question is more related to kernel development. Power related configurations are under [drivers/power](https://github.com/devkingsteam/android_kernel_samsung_universal7885/tree/se9.0/drivers/power) in kernel tree.

Comment: Is the question off-topic? Should I remove it then? I already looked at the drivers in the power directory, the problem is that I don't know which one of them is being used. But I'll try to use grep to look for keywords in the files.