# Is it possible to boot a Android smartphone without battery with charging wire on?

Tags: applications, battery, charging, boot

## Problem

The title of this post seems a funny challenge. But frankly, there are a lot of worthy points involved in this question.

If a Android phone support rapid charging. If its battery is removed, but the charging USB line is connected. Then push the power button. Is it possible to launch it normally?

## My experiment

I have a Huawei Honor 9, It is nice condition phone.

I open its back closure and lift the motherboard. Then the bottom of battery exposed. I use credit card to flip the battery against glue. After that, I detach the battery wire from the motherboard.

Then, I put motherboard back and put the back closure on. I connected the charging line.

After push the power button. The boot-flash logo appears. However, this state last for a long time (much longer than normal situation).

When it told me to input password. The thing goes wrong. It indicated that several service (Google service, Huawei Service and UI) is not properly launched. When I input my password. There is only a empty screen with only background wallpaper and a notification bar.

The notification bar show there are 2% of battery. No application is able to launch.

## My confusion

Is this result from the protective mechanism of Android system? (Because when battery is beyond some percent, the system will automatically turn off).

How nowadays Android smartphone determine the remaining charge in battery?
As the charging voltage is higher than the voltage in full-charge.

Is it the normal condition that the system cannot launch correctly without battery? Or it is because I might broke some part of circuit when I disassembly this smartphone?

Comment: Very related: [Using Android phone without battery](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/174862/using-android-phone-without-battery). Also for battery level reading: [How does the Android estimate the battery level without a current sensor?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46160/how-does-the-android-estimate-the-battery-level-without-a-current-sensor)

Comment: The best way to answer your last question is to reconnect the battery and see if it works normal again.